# Fetch row and explode - PHP mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, row, fetch, explode

Here is my code:

```
$postsql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='{$_GET['id']}'";
$posts = mysqli_query($connect,$postsql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connect));
$post = mysqli_fetch_array($posts);

$postAuthor = $post['author'];
$postDate = $post['date'];

$postCat = mysqli_fetch_row($post['cat']);// I've tags here separated by commas.
$postCatTag = explode(",",$postCat);

$postText = $post['text'];

echo "<img class='view_newsimg' src='{$postImg}'>
<h3 class='lath'>{$postTitle}</h3>
<ul class='det'><li class='adc'>avtori: {$postAuthor}</li>
<li class='adc'>TariRi: {$postDate}</li>
<li class='adc'>kategoria: <a href='#'>{$postCatTag}</a></li>"; // tags are shown here
echo <<<TEXT
<p class="news">{$postText}</p>
TEXT;
```

As a result for tag section in browser it displays:
 kategoria: **Array**
instead of displaying tags from table.
Why? How can get desired result?

Comment: If you want to display the list of tags then don't explode the list.

Comment: but there are tags more then one, and i want them to have separate links.

Comment: You should use a loop then.

Comment: what kind of out put you need for tags?

Comment: i need separated links shown side by side

Answer (score 0):

`$postCatTag` is an array. Array to string conversions always results in `Array`. You could use the [`implode`](http://php.net/implode)-function to impode an array with a given seperator:

```
implode(', ', $postCatTag);
```

Or you can just use `$postCat` since that is already a string (tags seperated by `','`).

Comment: I know, see last line of my answer. The implode-part was for completeness, and in case he wanted a custom separator.

Comment: If you already have the comma separated value in variable than what is the need of implode?

Comment: Maybe because `tag1, tag2, tag3` looks better than `tag1,tag2,tag3`. I didn't recommend to implode again with the same separator as used with `explode`

Comment: Does your db also include the spaces after the comma? In that case just replace `{$postCatTag}` with `{$postCat}`. Otherwise use `...<a href='#'>" . implode(', ', $postCatTag) . "</a>...`

Answer (score 0):

$postCatTag is an array. Arrays cannot be displayed by echo.

Use loop for this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($postCatTag),$i++){

  echo "<li class='adc'>kategoria: <a href='#'>$postCatTag[$i]</a></li>";  

}
```

Comment: and how to insert this?

Comment: replace
    `<li class='adc'>kategoria: <a href='#'>{$postCatTag}</a></li>";`
with my code
Check and let me know.

Comment: There was a small error in my code. I re-edited it in my answer. Its `$i<count($postCatTag)` not `$i<=count($postCatTag)`

Comment: just replace? like this: `echo "<img class='view_newsimg' src='{$postImg}'><h3 class='lath'>{$postTitle}</h3><ul class='det'><li class='adc'>avtori: {$postAuthor}</li><li class='adc'>TariRi: {$postDate}</li>
for($i=0;$i<count($postCatTag),$i++){

  echo "<li class='adc'>kategoria: <a href='#'>$postCatTag[$i]</a></li>";  

}";` it shows nothing/ replaced (") with (') and result was: `<li class='adc'>TariRi: 2014-08-22 13:00:00</li>
for(=0;<count(Array),++){

  echo '<li class='adc'>kategoria: <a href='#'></a></li>';  

}`

Comment: Thats because your array $postCatTag is empty. Dont replace (") with ('). Compiler reads and convert everything inside (") but when it comes accross (') it simply prints it. write `print_r($postCatTag)` somewhere and see the result. It will display content inside array. Will help you to debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo "<li class='adc'>kategoria:'; 
    for($i=0;$i<count($postCatTag),$i++)
    {

              echo "<a href='#'>$postCatTag[$i]</a>";  

    }
    echo "</li>";
```

Hope it will work for you.